# Making a bash script to replace a string in multiple files with provided extension

Tags: bash, unix

I know it's been asked many times but for some reason my script won't work. It will work when I provide a file name,

```
3)
    echo "provide a string to find"
    read stringA
    echo "provide a string to write"
    read stringB
    echo
sed -i -e 's/'"$stringA"'/'"$stringB"'/g' ~/Desktop/skrypcik/*.$ext
;;
esac
```

the $ext is provided earlier as an extension. when I change the * with file name and leave $ext there - it will work.

for example, I have 2 .txt files named aaa.txt & bbb.txt, they will be left untouched with this script being run, but when I change the path to ~/Desktop/skrypcik/aaa.$ext, set $ext as txt, it will work and change the aaa.txt properly.

sorry for the confussion, I'm just learning bash and I've seen "sed" being used with just "sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' *" that works very well. what's wrong with mine?

Thank you

edit: okay, apparently I was lacking permissions on that file, after changing it to proper ones it works correctly.

after tweaking it is all good now, thank you.

```
3)
echo "provide a string to find"
read stringA
echo "provide a string to replace"
read stringB
echo
sed -i '.backup' 's/'"$stringA"'/'"$stringB"'/g' ./*.$ext
echo "backups were created"
        for x in ./*.$ext.backup; do
        echo $x
done
;;
esac
```

Comment: Try `sed 's/e/E/g' ~/Desktop/skrypcik/*.$ext` without a case/esac and continue debugging

Comment: thank you for responses. I debugged it in a separate file without any cases and all, it went smooth but after I realised I need to give proper permissions to the file to make it modify existing files. I will edit my question and mark it as solved. since it really was my first bash script, I had no idea about things like this and Mac terminal didn't shout at me about permissions so... there's that.

Comment: You should always provide the output. In this instance it would have been -bash: ./script.bash: Permission Denied